# How to get a local website live on web/internet?

Tags: html, jakarta-ee, web, cloud, web-hosting

I am a newbie in website creation. I know J2EE, JSP and even a bit of PHP. I have a local site built. But now I want to put it on web/internet. Can someone tell me steps what to do (in detail)? I what to know all stpes and vendors which you think can provide me these functionality.

Is it good to take my site to cloud?
I have a website built on J2EE servlets and JSPs and MySQL database.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have created your website,here are the steps you can follow to put it live:

```
    1.first you need to buy Domain name for your website,for this you can visit
   GOdaddy.com or Bigrock.compare the prices and buy whichever is best.

    2.you need to buy Server space to host your website.
    again you can go to above mentioned sites and choose your plan,they also 
    provide cloud    services.

    3.and i think you must be aware that Cloud is nothing 
   But cluster of virtual servers which is nowadays best option to keep 
   your data safe.

    4.now yo need a FTP to transfer your file from localhost 
   to Remote server.FILEZILLA is an opensource application used 
   widely for the purpose.you may choose other also according to your need.
```

Comment: Getting domain name for website is just a single time charge I feel. Whereas point2 i.e getting server space will be a recurring expense according to me. Can you tell me more about it.

Comment: @vishram0709 you have 3 options:1.make your system a server(which i am strictly against),2.you can also get free hosting service but that will not be secure plus lots of headche.3.if you are very serious about your website than my suggestion is buy a linux hosting plan.

Comment: Buy shared hosting plans for small uses. Your name suggests that you are from India. We have some cheap hosting plans here ($1.95/year).